# how to save "Total Rows Affected" as an integer variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to save the total rows affected when running any given query, as a variable in my T-SQL query. Put simply, if a query I run returns 2348 records, I want the integer variable named `Total` to equal 2348. That way I can use `if` statements which run additional code if the total number of rows found by a given query is 0.

I have declared a variable `@TOTAL` and set it equal to a sub-query, which, when run independently will return the amount of lines which I want my `int` variable `@TOTAL` to hold.

So if the sub-query returns 490 lines, for example, I want the `int` variable @TOTAL to equal 490.

```
DECLARE @TOTAL int

set @TOTAL = (select distinct TRADE_REP_ORIG
from trade_archive
where error_code = 'r'
group by TRADE_FIRM_ORIG, TRADE_OFFICE_ORIG, TRADE_REP_ORIG)

print @TOTAL
```

I have tried using the `count()` function within the sub-query, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @TOTAL int

select @TOTAL = COUNT(DISTINCT TRADE_REP_ORIG)
from trade_archive
where error_code = 'r'

print @TOTAL
```

Note that a `GROUP BY` has no effect on the outcome when selecting distinct values.

Comment: This works great, and is prefferabble because of the nature of data within the table. Just using @@ROWCOUNT returns a count of the rows, which it is supposed to do, but using the subquery counts the data in a different way, which is what I was trying to do at first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

i.e.

```
Select @@ROWCOUNT as Total, *
From TableName
```

Comment: This doesn't neccesarily work in my case (I am not just trying to count rows, I am trying to aggregate specific rows in the table based on certain criteria) but I can definitely see how useful @@ROWCOUNT can be in the future.